# is it possible to set a twig in routing.yml?

Tags: theming

I am working with Opigno, which may be helpful to know.

My end goal is to have my own twig file for the page that shows this information from the module.

Here's the routing.yml entry:

```
# Module result page.
opigno_module.module_result:
  path: 'module/{opigno_module}/result/{user_module_status}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\opigno_module\Controller\OpignoModuleController::userResult'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'user_module_status.view'
  options:
    parameters:
      opigno_module:
        type: entity:opigno_module
      user_module_status:
        type: entity:user_module_status
```

I was hoping that I could add a `"_theme: 'somepath'"` so that I can use my own twig file here. Unfortunately, the link on the D8 site has "TODO" next to _theme.

Comment: IIRC `_theme` was destined to be used to select which theme, not twig template, was used for a particular route. Then, again IIRC, it was removed and hasn’t been replaced. I’m pretty sure the answer to this will be “not unless you create that system yourself” (assuming it’s even feasible)

Comment: Feasible yes. Templates in D8 are invoked by a `#theme` key in a render array and building/returning a render array is the job of the controller. There you can use a fixed route parameter with the arbitrary name `_theme` and put it into the render array.

Comment: You may want to have a look at Samuel Mortenson's [Single File Components](https://www.drupal.org/project/sfc), pretty hot stuff currently ongoing.